# Is inheritance the best solution for controllers with highly similar code?

Tags: symfony, inheritance, crud

I have an application with the following controller (all Read/Write operations are forwarded to an external API):

UserController:

- listAction
- showAction
- editAction
- createAction
- deleteAction

Now let's say i want to add a controller for products:

ProductController:

- listAction
- showAction
- editAction
- createAction
- deleteAction

90% of the code is very similar between the 2 controllers, in fact the differences are:

- Different attributes list in listAction, createAction, deleteAction
- Custom filtering in listAction

To avoid code duplication my idea is to use a structure like this one:

BaseController

- listAction
- showAction
- editAction
- createAction
- deleteAction

UserController and ProductController both inherit from BaseController
and define methods such as getListAttributes()... to be used by the parent class, if any custom behaviour is needed for example in listAction for ProductController i would just override it there.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Controller inheritance seldom worked well for me.  There is usually just enough differences between actions to require some sort of hack or override.  If it work for you then great.  Another approach is to move each action into it's own class and then actually share the action itself.

Comment: "Another approach is to move each action into it's own class and then actually share the action itself." you mean using composition?

Comment: Not really.  Instead of a controller having multiple actions, make multiple controllers each containing exactly one action.  Not as bad as it may seem at first and, if, for example, a show action only needs a different repository and template injected to show different types of entities then you can use the exact same ShowAction code.  Of course this approach is not for everyone.  I found using inheritance to be difficult to maintain but your experience might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like the name `BaseController` may be you can find a more specific name link to your use case (with CRUD or your external API name).

Otherwise your approach is good. If you have already an existing inheritance you can also create a PHP Trait.

And if your controllers and your methods become more complex, you can create custom symfony events in order to override them without coupling more your code to your `BaseController` and without define again the whole method/action and the logic behind.